# Angular translate - choose another key if not valid

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Is there any way to tell ng-translate to use another key if the first doesn't exist? We can achieve that by using **translate-default**:

```
<any translate="possibly.non.existing.key" translate-default="Translation failed"></any>
```

But I also want to i18e the default translation, so I use this:

```
<any translate="possibly.non.existing.key" translate-default="{{'existing.key' | translate}}"></any>
```

And here is the problem - if there is no `'existing.key'` key the default translation will also fail. Is there any **safe** way to achieve that? E.g.:

```
<any translate="possibly.non.existing.key || existing.key" translate-default="Translation failed"></any>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own directive with $translate.instant;

But it's bad design. Good design is to use fallback language, which has all translations available.

Answer (score 0):

if `possibly.non.existing.key` string we can compare with blank string

```
 <any translate="possibly.non.existing.key===""?existing.key : possibly.non.existing.key" translate-default="Translation failed"></any>
```

Comment: It won't work, "possibly.non.existing.key" is not an object, but a string

Comment: so you can compare with "", let me make the changes.

Comment: No, it always shows Translation failed, because it treats whole condition as a single key which of course doesn't exists.